# Motion of Particle Described by Given Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields

I encountered a problem wherein I was given that the electric lines of force in a region varies as $$x^2+y^2=1$$  A charged particle was initially at rest at $(1,0)$.
I had to answer whether the particle moves along the circular line of force or not which I figured out easily as there is no centripetal force and it does not move along the circular lines of force however later I try to find out what the actual path might be but I am unable to write an equation for the same. Please help.

Comment: Do you know how to use Newton's second law and how to solve differential equations?

Comment: @AaronStevens I know the second law but I am not too proficient with solving differentials. I only know a few basic 1st degree equations like those of SHM but not their actual methods rather their general solutions.

Comment: There equation of your electric field doesn't make sense. That's just the equation of a circle. What's the actual vector field?

Comment: @AaronStevens This is all that's given. The question didn't actually ask for the equation of motion however I was wondering is there a way to do with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find an equation for motion, you must first find an equation for the instantaneous acceleration at a point ($F/M = a$), once you have that you can set it equal to our instantaneous change in velocity ($a = dv/dt$) and then integrate for position (not forgetting to plug in the initial condition into the equation for your $X$ position). You must split the force into $X$ and $Y$ components and do this twice if you want to use cartesian coordinates, or you can convert to polar for one equation.

Comment: also you do not need a centripetal force to move in a circle if the force vectors are all tangential to the circle

Comment: Okk so how can I show that the force vectors here are not all tangential to the circle mathematically?

Comment: Also how do I split the force? By partial differentiation?

Comment: How can a particle move in a circle without a centripetal force

Comment: @AdityaGarg If you have (force vectors that are tangential to a circle and all equal they will naturally push an object along the path of the circle. This isn't one force pulling inwards, but many different forces in different positions along the circle. Like if you put a leaf in a whirlpool it will move in a circle but there is no force inwards (on the leaf) it is simply following the flow of water.

Comment: @StackUpPhysics to show that the force vectors are not all tangential you need to derive an equation for the tangent line of the circle which is the slope of the line and prove that it is not always parallel with the force vectors at that point (you could do this with an inner product or a dot product). And to split the force into x and y components you'd have to use a trig identity (cos or sin), so in the end you'd probably want to go with polar coordinates so that your equations would actually be reasonably workable.